# weak solution of poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider the equation , with $u\in H^1$
$$\begin{cases}\Delta u = f & \text{in }\Omega\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0 & \text{in } \partial \Omega\end{cases}$$
where $\nu$ is the (unitary) exterior normal to the boundary $\partial \Omega$.

($\Omega$ is a very very nice bounded set)

I want to show that $u$ is a solution of the problem if and only if $\int_{\Omega}fdx=0$.

So the weak form is (using green's):$$\int_{\Omega}Du.Dv \ dx=\int_{\Omega}fv \ dx$$

for all $v\in H^1$.

of course If $u$ is a solution we have that $\int_{\Omega}fdx=0$. (taking $v=1$).

But I can't prove the rest. Some hints will be useful :).

Thanks alot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You showed that if the problem is solvable then $\int_{\Omega}fdx=0$, suppose that $\int_{\Omega}fdx=0$ and show that the problem is solvable you  need to proof a existence theorem, or use one if you know some.

Edit:

try to use Fredholm alternative

for every $f ∈ L^2(Ω) $the boundary value problem
(∗)$ \triangle u = f \,\,in\,\, Ω,\,\,\, \frac{\partial u}{\partial v}= 0 \,\,\,on \,\,\,∂Ω$
has a unique solution $u\in H^1(\Omega)$

**OR**

) there is a nontrivial solution $u ∈ H^1
(Ω)$ of
$\triangle u = 0 $ in Ω, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}= 0 $on $\partialΩ$.
In case this case  we have additionally
the system is solvable ⇔ $<h,f>_{L^2}=0$, $v\in L^2 = 0 $ for every weak solution $v ∈ H^1
(Ω)$

Comment: Like lax-Milgram ? But how ? I can't see it

Comment: I edited my answer.